# Prevent navigation with WebKit

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I would like to prevent users from being able to click on links (or buttons with links) in a WebKit web view, in effect preventing navigation. It seems that this is possible with a UIWebView. How can I accomplish this with a WKView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

preventing this type of action can be done in a number of ways and heavily depends on how you want to prevent it.

The absolute simplest would be to tell the WKWebView to stop loading in all cases but the initial load

```
var isInitialLoad = true

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    if self.isInitialLoad {
        self.isInitialLoad = false
    } else {
        webView.stopLoading()
    }
}
```

Be aware doing it in this fashion would cause you to fire
webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError)
where error.code = -999

You can use evaluateJavascript() to find all anchor tags/buttons on the page and disable/handle them via javascript.

Either way, what you can directly do to a webview can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKWebView

Comment: I come here and see a downvote. I don't understand, this is definitely the answer.

Comment: Thanks Arturo, perhaps it was for my example which had a bug (now fixed).  Or perhaps someone doesn't like the question itself.

I am somewhat curious what lead the original poster to need to disable all navigation in all cases, likely there is a better solution to the problem, but without the context of the problem, its hard to give a better answer.

In my opinion .stopLoading() shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary.  ie. the client side app code identifies a failure condition that the server is not, or cannot be aware of.  Ideally stopping all navigation is a server side issue.

Comment: Well, in my specific case, stopping navigation was used to redirect the request to the system browser instead. Maybe there was a better way, but this worked for me.

Comment: Depends on if you have access to the server side code.  If you have access to the server side as a for instance, you could set up a javascript interface into your app that notifies the app that a system browser should be invoked with a provided url.